# Does a fridge thermostat need a ground connection?

Tags: electrical, refrigerator, thermostat, grounding

I've recently replaced the thermostat in my fridge with a new unit with a much higher temperature range ([this unit](http://www.tobins.com.au/HTML/ItemHTML/TS-040S.htm) specifically).

The unit I took out had a ground connector & the original wiring had it connected.  The new unit does not have a place for a ground connection, so I've not connected it.

Everything is running fine, but should I run the ground wire from the fridge somewhere?  What could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the new unit does not have a ground connection then it doesn't need one.

The ground wire was for the original thermostat so there should be no bad effects from not having it connected to anything. Any other component in the fridge that requires grounding will still be grounded through it's own wire.

Just make sure that you've insulated the end.